# Regular expression (regex) for only a few characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using the following function in javascript and it restricts some characters (accented and special). Would allow the user to enter the following characters:

á é í ó ú Á É Í Ó Ú : - _ ç Ç ã ~e õ Ã Õ Â Ê Ô

but I'm not succeeding in doing, could help me?

NOTE: The code below is what I currently have no idea how to make a regex that allows the characters cited

my function with regex:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
   var $th = $(this);
   $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, function(str) {                                     
        return '';
   });
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JavaScript supports direct Unicode programming, you should just be able to use

```
/[áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ:-_çÇã~eõÃÕÂÊÔ]/
```

Since `[]` chooses *one* of the characters (or character ranges) within.

Comment: Note that `~` and `e` probably aren't what you wanted there.

Answer (score 2):

Use the unicode hex value for those specific characters (which can be found at unicode-table.com) and include them within your character class. So, for example, to allow the `á` and `é` you would modify your expression to:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \u00E1\u00E9]/
```

Comment: Does JavaScript not support Unicode as in my answer below? If it does not, I should delete it.  (JS isn't a language I'm terribly familiar with.)